# ASP include file into variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, templates, server-side-includes

I have a template.aspx file the contains code like this:

```
    <html>
    ....
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    ----sideMenu---
.........
    <div id="body">
        <%=pageContent%>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have a file index.aspx
with the code:

```
<%
    Dim pageContent = ""
%>
<!--#include virtual="template.aspx"-->
```

I want to insert in pageContent a lot of html code and asp code
without connecting strings like this:

```
pageContent = "<div class..." &_
" bla bla bla " & aspVariable &_
"more divs and html and asp variables"
.
.
.
```

actually i want a dyanmic pages i dont want write the template html codes each pages i want that only the pageContent are change.

Comment: Why don't you put ALL of the page content into it's own page, and just include that too?

Comment: because i have a lot of pages
i have template.aspx that contain all the html codes (metas etc...)
i want to insert into part of template file dynamic content of a lot pages

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to take content from an include file and put it into a variable? (That seems to be what you're asking but it's not what you show in your last code sample.) Are you also trying to put ASP code into a variable?

Comment: i edited the main message I hope that now it is understandable

Comment: @Dijkgraaf What appears as though they are using Classic ASP? Not this `Dim pageContent = ""` that's for sure, in fact apart from similarities none of that code is Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more common to create a handful of template files to be included in each page of your ASP app. Such as:
header.inc (might contain site, banner... top of page stuff)
topNav.inc (might contain code to generate the top navigation bar)
leftNav.inc (take a guess ;))
bottomCopy.inc (might have text links as site map and copyright statement.

Then, in each page, include all where they should live. For example, in my page called "theFirst.aspx", I might have:

```
<!-- #include file = "cacheprevent.inc" -->
<!-- #include file = "accesscheck.inc" -->
<!-- #include file = "header.inc" -->
<!-- #include file = "topNav.inc" -->
<!-- #include file = "leftNav.inc" -->
<%
' Here goes the rest of your code to generate content for this specific page
%>
<!-- #include file = "bottomCopy.inc" -->
```

All this assumes it *is* in ASP-Classic, as you've tagged your post, at least in part.

... and you could in some cases, combine the top four... if all pages would have the same layout regions.

Comment: The tag is wrong, it's clearly ASP.Net as the file extensions are `.aspx`.